# typescript how to handle/distinguish the nested object in union

Tags: typescript

I have a following example while 3 objects sharing some common configs inside the nested object.

There are two functions that does exactly the same thing, the second one follows the typescript strictly but extremely verbose. The first one is the common one we used to have in javascript but typescript will raise a error due to the difference inside the `configs`.

Are there any ways I can handle it like the first function but still ensure the type safety?

typescript playground for the below code [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwJYGMoF4oG8BQV9QoD2AdgGZIDmCAXNngY8QLbOl0LABOSJlA3A3wBfQY1CQA-HQBEAI0SoZg4ThwToAUQAe3OBnpNSFanVyMjrdlE48%20Yi-gi6ucDt14ChUUd43SoGWc9ZRxVdXAtFzgAJgNzAmJyKlpDR0IiKxJ3Oy90qGDXGJzPBxEyqH9ZQtjQ8IB6esqACyQEKGbEAq4uIi4oOQgUOABXBGhgdoATIggEEgByYCgppGBPEbbmlugkk3a2qDJe5gHFND6C6IA6HDIRkhR10kq54AAKXjAR4Dp4ZDQAB8oDo9FBgaCigAaDJZEp8ACUf3O4JB0VRkNiaXwSDIUE%20JG%20wGuGgw6Ew8nOMnBwK%20PxJkTJFJq1MBtMJ9NJ5OZ0RiMgR2IsXAgwBGXBIgvy12ldOAUO8%20T2KTMCvyBGl11l1yV1HlavSLDY2VhRr1%20p8qpE3lUjGFovFUFlKjU90ezwlwDeMQJRORAIx6IhvJhhustk8SNgKKDYJjRUFuPxWq55MCCgB-MlBDtYolCX1GtlZv1OtS%20fN%20ELHOJpeLFZN1lDJDr%20Rt6TbVsYiZ9nMZ3MCLIF5dtItzWccVaJLYNxmV47Vk-ptctaqbdCb08cHYs2%2033eTfdTQV5meH2dHDrPE5l1c3FlLKvr6pvRO1s91K8VmSN6%20-pDvjDboB1reDmDpOmEag4EAA)

```
type Basic = {
    configs: {
        common: string;
    };
    type?: "basic";
}

type Extra = {
    configs: {
        common: string;
        extra: string;
    };
    type?: "extra";
}

type Extra2 = {
    configs: {
        common: string;
        extra2: string;
    };
    type?: "extra2";
}

// this has error because ts cannot determine the configs is from basic or extra for the nested obj.
function test(input: Basic | Extra | Extra2, common: string): Basic | Extra | Extra2 {
    if (input.type === "basic" || input.type === "extra" || input.type === "extra2") {
        return {
            ...input,
            configs: {
                ...input.configs,
                common: common,
            }
        }
    }
    return input;
}

// this one is fine but verbose
function test2(input: Basic | Extra | Extra2, common: string): Basic | Extra | Extra2 {
    if (input.type === "basic") {
        return {
            ...input,
            configs: {
                ...input.configs,
                common: common,
            }
        }
    }
    if (input.type === "extra") {
        return {
            ...input,
            configs: {
                ...input.configs,
                common: common,
            }
        }
    }
    if (input.type === "extra2") {
        return {
            ...input,
            configs: {
                ...input.configs,
                common: common,
            }
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like type assertion can handle my problem easily if I'm absolutely sure I will only update the common property, (where I guess it's not truly type safe ?).

```
  if (input.type === "basic" || input.type === "extra" || input.type === "extra2") {
        return {
            ...input,
            configs: {
                ...input.configs,
                common: common,
            }
        } as Basic | Extra | Extra2
    }
```

=======

Update: the **truly type-safe** approach that guarantees I will only accept/update common property.

```
    type OmitNever<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
     [K in keyof T as T[K] extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
    };
    type SharedProperties<T> = OmitNever<Pick<T, keyof T>>;

    // do my common update here.
    const commonConfigs: SharedProperties<(Basic | Extra | Extra2)["configs"]> = {
        common: common,
        //extra: 2, // you will get ts error here if you try to insert extra type
    }
    if (input.type === "basic" || input.type === "extra" || input.type === "extra2") {
        return {
            ...input,
            configs: {
                ...input.configs,
                ...commonConfigs,
            }
        } as Basic | Extra | Extra2
    }
```